# Visual Studio 2019 keeps crashing when running StyleCop version 6.2

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2019, stylecop

I am currently working on a C# API in .netCore 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.3. When I'm coding on a class and I right click then select "Run StyleCop" the app will show my violations but then the whole Visual Studio freezes and crashes.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: "What can I do to fix this?" - StyleCop is open-source, so run a debug build of it and find out what makes it freeze and then submit a PR. https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop

Comment: I'll suggest a different solution. Use Directory.Build.props to enable stylecop rules on Visual Studio.
https://thomaslevesque.com/2017/09/18/common-msbuild-properties-and-items-with-directory-build-props/

Comment: My operating system is WIndows 10 Pro